# WPF giving keyboard focus to user control

Tags: wpf

I have a window that displays a number of user controls. One of these needs to expose some keyboard shortcuts, which I've defined like so:-

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="N"
                Modifiers="Control"
                Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
    ..etc..
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

The user control itself has a variety of child controls - TextBoxes, a DataGrid, buttons, etc. The keyboard shortcuts will be used to manipulate items in the DataGrid.

When I click on the UC, the keyboard shortcuts may or may not work, depending on where I've clicked. E.g. they won't work after clicking on the DataGrid, but will work after clicking on a TextBox or Button.

I'd assumed that clicking anywhere on the UC would have naturally given it focus. Is it something to do with keyboard focus and mouse focus being two different things? Not really had to handle this sort of thing before now.

How do I get the keyboard shortcuts to work - either when the UC first appears, or whenever the user clicks anywhere on it?

Comment: There is a difference between being focused and hosting a focused control. If your `UserControl` is focused, the `KeyBinding` should work. However, if the focus is on a control within the usercontrol, the keybinding depends on, whether the focused control is handling key strokes or allows them to bubble up to parent controls until the usercontrol is reached. So the basic options are: make sure all childs are bubbling key strokes up to the usercontrol or ensure that keystrokes are caught by the usercontrol before reaching the child controls (`Preview...` events)

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958235/keybinding-woes there might be more going on...

Comment: @grek40 There are no event handlers on any of the controls that would be trapping keypresses. I'm beginning to think it's a quirk with how some of these controls handle keyboard focus. E.g. if I add a row to the DataGrid then click on the row, keyboard shortcuts work. However if I click elsewhere in the DataGrid (e.g. column headings or the "empty" area) then the shortcuts don't work.

Comment: The `DataGrid` __is a Control__ and I suspect you don't know whether it is trapping keypresses (or more precisely, you do know, but you don't want it)