# WPF MenuItem Command.Executed not firing, but Command.CanExecute does

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate, commandbinding

This has been driving me mad for a few days now!

I cannot get the Executed part of the command to fire on anything below 'Level 1' of my menu. I can see that the 'CanExecute' callback is always called on all menu items and the callback always returns true.

Please could someone point me in the correct direction?  I know I could add an implementation of ICommand in MyTypes:MyMenuDescriptorType but this does not fit into the model that I am trying to achieve.

Many thanks in advance

```
private void CreateActionCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void CreateActionCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("This only happens on Level 1");
}

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="CreateAction" Text="CreateAction"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>    
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Menu>
        <Menu.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource CreateAction}" Executed="CreateActionCommand_Executed" CanExecute="CreateActionCommand_CanExecute"/>               
        </Menu.CommandBindings>         
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="MyMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Description}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{StaticResource CreateAction}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>                   
            </Style>                                        
        </Menu.Resources>           
        <MenuItem Header="Root Level">
            <MenuItem Header="Level 1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfThings}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyMenuStyle}">
                <MenuItem.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                        DataType="{x:Type MyTypes:MyMenuDescriptorType}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" 
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyMenuStyle}"/>
                </MenuItem.Resources>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

UPDATE:  I have since worked out what was going wrong. My simplified example did not update the property 'MyListOfThings'.  If I update the 'MyListOfThings' in the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event of the Menu then the control does strange things and the commands do not fire.  However, if I update the property in the MouseOver event then everything works as expected!

I am not sure why this is.  Perhaps someone could explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a DelegateCommand, you can find the [snippet code here](http://geekytheory.com/tutorial-windows-phone-4-introduccion-mvvm-parte-4/).

after in your MenuItem, will look like:

```
<MenuItem Header="DoSomething" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
```

and in your ViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        DoSomethingCommand= new DelegateCommand(DoSomethingCommandExec, DoSomethingCommandCanExec);
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand{ get; private set; }

    private bool DoSomethingCommandCanExec()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void DoSomethingCommandExec()
    {
        // DoSomethingCommand
    }
```

I think this is a good way to implement it. Each MenuItem will have a Command. You can have Menuitems into MenuItem who can bind to a command same as here.

like:

```
<MenuItem Header="DoSomething" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}">
    <MenuItem Header="DoSomething" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Hope Helps.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365582/how-to-implement-commands-to-use-ancestor-methods-in-wpf) question. It worked for me:

haml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu1">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu1" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Menu1Executed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ContextMenu1}" Tag="{Binding}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Content" Margin="2"/>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Menu1Executed = new DelegateCommand(ShowMenu1);
    }

    public ICommand Menu1Executed { get; set; }

    private void ShowMenu1(object obj)
    {
        // Yay!
    }
}

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```